# Excel formula - convert date format of text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following column which is formatted as text and contains a date:

```
`Wed Jul 12 23:59:05 PDT 2017`
```

How can I convert this into an actual date in the `dd/mm/yyyy` format? I tried `=DATE(RIGHT(B4,4),MID(B4,5,3),MID(B4,9,2))` but without success.

Thanks

Comment: Excel dates aren't text. They are actually stored as *doubles*. How they appear, or the fact that they are considered dates at all, has to do with the cell's format. Once you get your formulat to work, the only thing you need to make the date appear a certain way is to change the cell's format

Comment: From Felix Kunz: Check https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/26/excel-convert-text-date/ Scroll a bit down and i think you will find your solution

Comment: The problem with the formula is that `Date` expect *numbers*, but `MID(B4,5,3)` extracts the *name* of the month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
=DATE(RIGHT(B4,4),MONTH(DATEVALUE(MID(B4,5,3)&1)),MID(B4,9,2))
```

See image for reference

[image]